# Is it possible to manually start Juju hooks?

Tags: juju

I know you can debug hooks in error state by running `juju debug-hooks nodemane` and then running `juju resolved --retry nodename`. Is it possible to run or rerun hooks that are not in an error state?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes using `actions` https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/actions

Actions are exposed as of Juju 1.23. In Juju 1.22, they are only enabled in the CLI when JUJU_DEV_FEATURE_FLAG=actions is set.

If you don't need the hooks to execute in a 'hook environment' then you can just execute them via ssh as a normal script.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to use 'juju run'.

juju run --unit someunit/1 'hooks/some-hook'

When using 'juju run' for a unit or all units of a service, the working directory is set to the charm, so you can access the hooks directly.

Comment: I suspect the hook environment will not be available then? `relation-get` and things like that?